# Online tool for generating mathematical equation image files

Tags: math, image

I'm looking for an online tool that will let me create a gif or png like this one:

[image]

Some kind of LaTex online service, with friendly examples?

Comment: StackExchange/Mathematics has an excellent LaTeX editor, then... screen copy!

Comment: I have made exactly what you are asking for [Latex Equation Toolbox](https://viktorstrate.github.io/latex-equation-toolbox/). It has a graphical math editor, and can automatically convert what you type to png and svg

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I use [Roger's Online Equation Editor](http://rogercortesi.com/eqn/index.php).

PNG, colors, transparent background and anti-aliasing are all included.

Comment: This is not working for me

Comment: I found this to work best http://www.latex2png.com/

Answer (score 11):

Personally, [iTex2Img](http://www.sciweavers.org/free-online-latex-equation-editor) is much better than [Roger's Online Equation Editor](http://rogercortesi.com/eqn/index.php). Here is a screenshot with an example:

[image]

Comment: This is old, but still worth commenting to say how excellent this tool is!

Answer (score 7):

http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

Answer (score 3):

I second hyperlogic's suggestion (http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) in that you can get the image using a GET url, e.g. http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%20%7D%20x%5E%7Bt%7D%20dt gives:

[image]

The main page helps you get the encoded url.

Answer (score 1):

I use [the TeXer](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/texer.php) for creating images from LaTeX.  It creates gifs with transparent background.

Comment: The Texer valid url are http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/texer.php

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for a solution and bumped into this. I tried most of the solutions suggested in this page. But I found the following that fit my needs. This is an easy to use REST API here.

http://api.toolswebtop.com/math/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

http://smarth.sourceforge.net/

and implemented also at http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=8997

Answer (score 0):

http://wolframalpha.com/
Works all the time :)

Answer (score 0):

The Online tool:
http://www.aprendematematicas.org.mx/profesores/latex.html#Editor

If you want to include it in your website:
http://www.codecogs.com/latex/about.php

Answer (score 0):

I maintain [ShareMath.com](http://ShareMath.com) which support MathML and can output a PNG permalink.

Comment: Not loading for me...

Comment: @Betlista send us your config using http://supportdetails.com (use support@scolab.com as the email)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mathjax.org
MathJax is an open source JavaScript display engine for mathematics that works in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Verified is wikipedia, you can use [sandbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Sandbox) and everything described in [help](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula) works fine.

I found no other page, where this equation can be created:

[image: mdist(A, P) & = |A_x - P_x| + |A_y - P_y| \ & =max(A_x - P_x, P_x - A_x) + max(A_y - P_y, P_y - A_y)]

Answer (score -3):

http://www.mr.ethz.ch/~majer/formula/formula.php