# Print Mathematical equation in Winform | Report

Tags: c#, winforms, report

I want to show Mathematical formula in Report in my winform application. I am aware about RDLC but during my testing I found I was not able to show it correctly (As per understanding, please let me know if I missed something). I also tried setting Placeholder property in RDLC to HTML - Interpret html tags as styles, but in vain.

eg. While showing x a [x^a] I got is showing xa [showing side by side]

How can I be able to show this kind of mathematical formula in RDLC report. or can anyone suggest any good reporting service by which I can achieve this.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: From your example `x a [x^a]` you say ends up like `xa[x^a]` so that means the report doesn't treat spaces as multiplications? Why not explicitly put in the `*`'s in?

Comment: post some photos for your question

Comment: @JeremyThompson , Thanks for your comment. Can you please explain in some more details or give any url to understand ??

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest/best/reliable solution would be to save Math formula's to image and include the images in the Report:

[Online tool for generating mathematical equation image files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115459/online-tool-for-generating-mathematical-equation-image-files)

This is [How to show images on an RDLC report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570747/how-to-show-images-on-an-rdlc-report)

Answer (score 0):

I use [Roger's Online Equation Editor](http://rogercortesi.com/eqn/index.php).

PNG, colors, transparent background and anti-aliasing are all included.

And used [Converting math equations to C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30615/Converting-math-equations-to-C) for inline code math equations