# Playground for web prototyping HTML CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, ide, development-environment

I'm looking for online playgrounds that let you code and preview.
I suggest single tool for answer, so it can be voted separately.
Please include a few features and limitations and a screenshot if possible.

In advance, I know that this kind of question is prone to being flagged off-topic, but I've seen this kind of question that they put answers to vote.

> What topics can I ask about here?
>   - software tools commonly used by programmers;

Example: [Online tool for generating mathematical equation image files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115459/online-tool-for-generating-mathematical-equation-image-files)

Answer (score 1):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/)

[image]

Features

- External Resources
- Resizable Panels
- Syntax Highlighting
- Ajax simulation
- JSHint (check for syntax errors)
- TidyUp (apply indentation to code)

Cons

- No code completion
- No live preview
- Cannot collapse panels

Answer (score 1):

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/new#)

[image]

- Bootstrap in
- HTML/CSS/JS
- Libraries
- Themes
- Templates
- Buttons to insert html tags and snippets
- Mobile size preview

cons

- no live preview

Answer (score 0):

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/)

[image]

- Resizable Panels
- Toggle HTML/CSS/JS/Console/Output
- Import/Export Gist
- Live Preview

Answer (score 0):

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/)

[image]

- Live Output
- Easy to add External files
- Keyboard Shortcuts
- Free Account
- Ability to Follow others
- Ability to Fork
- Supports Tags
- Minimizable/Hidable Panels
- SEO friendly

Comment: thanks @Vitim.us -- was just getting to that...  :)

Answer (score 0):

[Dabblet](http://dabblet.com/)

[image]

- HTML/CSS Focused
- Prefix free CSS
- Live preview

Cons

- Fixed Panel size
- Limited JS support

Answer (score 0):

[CSSDeck](http://cssdeck.com/)

[image]

- Live Preview
- You can use tools like Prefixfree, Normalize, and other Preprocessors like Jade, HAML, Stylus, Less, SASS, Coffeescript
- Zen Coding in HTML and CSS is also supported
- Code font-size can be adjusted. Code box alignment can also be changed to horizontal or vertical positions.
- You can set privacy settings to Super Private (only you will be able) to see your creation then or Private.

Answer (score 0):

[**LIVEWEAVE**](http://liveweave.com/)

It updates the layout without reloading the page, live preview option.
[image: Liveweave]

[CSSDESK](http://cssdeck.com/)

[image: Css Desk]

[DABBLET](http://dabblet.com/)

[image: Dabblet]

Answer (score 0):

[Liveweave](http://liveweave.com/)

[image]

- Live Mode
- Code-hinting for HTML, CSS and JavaScript
- Dark/Light Theme
- Download as Single file or zip
- Lorem ipsum generator
- Libraries
- Ruler
- Flexible Layout
- Real time CSS and JS validation
- Supports Emmet (formerly, Zen Coding)